# Apache Beam Word Count: Convert to Gradle (Groovy)

Tags: java, gradle, apache-beam

I am working with the quick start guide of Apache Beam:
https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java

I want to create a minimal setup with gradle, and want to test it with Direct Runner.
When I run this command which mentioned in the guide:

```
gradle clean execute -DmainClass=main.Main --args="--inputFile=sample.txt --output=counts"
```

Gradle fails with those error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'execute' not found in root project 'apache-beam-hello-world'.
```

So I think I am missing some settings in build.gradle,
I read the guide again and I found those code maybe related:

```
task("execute", JavaExec::class) {
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    mainClass.set(System.getProperty("mainClass"))
}
```

However, the code above is written in Kotlin,
so I have no idea what should I do now.

Here is my current build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "java-library"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.39.0"
    implementation "org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.39.0"
}

tasks.named("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

Update (2022-05-29T18:47:00Z):

I can just run the Main class and works fine with my Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my way to rewrite the same thing from Kotlin to Groovy and it works:

```
task execute(type: JavaExec) {
    mainClass = "main.Main"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Also, we need to add the repositories like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/" }
}
```